# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' while running angularJs and node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to AngularJS and was trying to get a basic code running. I want to use nodejs as my server.

My nodejs server file looks like this:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();   

app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

my index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<!-- Meta-Information -->
<!-- etc… -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="ACME Inc.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Vendor: Bootstrap Stylesheets http://getbootstrap.com -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Our Website CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="WebApp">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
    your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- Our Website Content Goes Here -->

<div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
<div ng-view></div>


<!-- Vendor: Javascripts -->
<!-- etc… -->

<!-- Our Website Javascripts -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <!-- etc… -->
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/projects">Projects Table</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('WebApp', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

/*
    * Configure the Routes
*/

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html",  controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html",controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/projects", {templateUrl: "partials/projects.html",  controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/contact", {templateUrl: "partials/contact.html",  controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/blog", {templateUrl: "partials/blog.html",controller: "BlogCtrl"})
    .when("/blog/post", {templateUrl: "partials/blog_item.html", controller: "BlogCtrl"})
    // else 404
    .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});
}]);



/**
 * Controls the Blog
 */
app.controller('BlogCtrl', function (/* $scope, $location, $http */) {
  console.log("Blog Controller reporting for duty.");
});

/**
 * Controls all other Pages
 */
app.controller('PageCtrl', function (/* $scope, $location, $http */) {
  console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");

  // Activates the Carousel
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
  });

  // Activates Tooltips for Social Links
  $('.tooltip-social').tooltip({
    selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]"
  })
});
```

When I run server.js I get a blank web page. When I check the console output I get the following error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' at Line 1`

I also get an error from angular.js

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/modulerr?p0=WebApp&p1=[$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/nomod?p0=WebApp
>   t/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:6:450
>   Yc/b.modulehttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:20:466
>   Yc/b.modulehttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:20:1
>   e/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:33:199
>   q@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:7:278
>   e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:33:139
>   ec@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:36:252
>   dc/c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:18:139
>   dc@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:18:356
>   Wc@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:17:435
>   @http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:211:1
>   a@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:144:237
>   ne/c/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:31:223
>   q@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:7:278
>   ne/c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js:31:207

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's in your `main.js` and `header.html`?

Comment: why using <span class ="highlight">  in config ?

Comment: Yip, remove `spans` in `app.config` and you have an extra `}]);` after `app.config`

Comment: @ngLover Updated the code. Still no difference

Comment: code looks gud , can u create the fiddle ?

Comment: The syntax error that you get indicates that the browser requested for a particular file (most likely a javascript file) but received an html file. Check the Network tab in Google Chrome for the request which failed. `expressjs` responds with the index.html file if it cannot find a particular static file requested.

Comment: @callmekatootie There are no errors in the network tab

Comment: @user1692342 By errors, I mean check the requests where a javascript file is requested but the server has responded with HTML file instead.

Comment: No errors such as that!

Comment: Ok. The `Syntax Error` that you get in the console - which file is raising it and which file is the error about?

Comment: Ok you were right. Main.js is returned as a html page. I was checking the type of file rather than the content. My bad sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this piece of code that is causing the problem:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

This will send back index.html for all requests from the clients, including those for `.js` and other non-html files. Hence, you are getting syntax errors as < is not valid JavaScript in isolation.

You either need to put conditionals in your `app.get` callback, or use a different path pattern other than `'*'`

Take a look at http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html which provides ways to handle this.

**EDIT**

The easiest way to serve static files will be to set the static directory. Adding the following above your `app.get` should do the trick based on your setup:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You can also remove `app.get('/js/'...`

Comment: I tried like this :
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

app.get('/js/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/js/main.js'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

Didnt work

Comment: where is your public folder, i.e. where is the 'js' folder located?

Comment: public is in my root folder. js folder is inside public. public folder is basically in same level as server.js and package.json

Comment: It works! Right Now I have handled the GET Request in server.js as 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); )
});